# Select and crop Image from gallery,Displayed in a Circular Shape Imageview

Tags: android, image, android-intent

I am trying to fetch Image from Gallery. when user chooses a picture from Gallery, they need to ask crop the Image then the cropped image should be displayed in ImageView.

Here's what I tried:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class Details extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView i1,i2;
    int num =2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
       android.support.v7.app.ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
       if (ab != null) {
           ab.hide();
       }
       i1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.prof1);
       i2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.prof2);
       i1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               Intent img_uopload = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
               img_uopload.putExtra("crop","true");
               img_uopload.putExtra("aspectX",1);
               img_uopload.putExtra("aspectY",1);
               img_uopload.putExtra("outputX",200);
               img_uopload.putExtra("outputY",200);
               img_uopload.putExtra("return-data",true);
               startActivityForResult(img_uopload,num);
           }
       });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == num && resultCode == RESULT_OK ){
            if(data!=null){
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                if(extras !=null){
                    Bitmap img = extras.getParcelable("data");
                    i1.setImageBitmap(img);
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Not Read",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here the bundle value returns null.

In android manifest, I have included.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

UAC :

1. when user clicks image button,Gallery Opens
2. when user chooses image from gallery,He/She should ask to crop the image
3. Cropped Image should placed in ImageView

Currently I am not able to use any Github libraries.

After choosing an image user needs to crop the image as like this:

[image]

This is my screen:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Crop intent check this :

```
    try {
        String picUri="your irl";

        Intent myCropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");

        myCropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
        myCropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        myCropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        myCropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        myCropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 128);
        myCropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 128);
        myCropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(myCropIntent, CROP_PIC_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

        String errorMessage = "No Activity found";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
```

else you can also use this crop library [simple-crop-image-lib](https://github.com/biokys/cropimage/tree/master/simple-crop-image-lib)

Rounded image view use this library [RoundedImageView](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView)

Comment: I will try your code..Currently i am not able to use any External libraries for this.. I have seen this tutorial but its not working for me..If you have time,please see the video once..   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=POhbjnqcKXo